# Error when inserting a UUID into YAML using "!!python/object"

Tags: pyyaml

For an automated test script, I would like to generate random UUID values at runtime, so I added some YAML that looks like this:

```
---
applicant:
  idNumbers:
    nationalId: !!python/object:uuid.uuid4
```

However, this generates an error when I try to `yaml.load` the value:

```
ConstructorError: expected a mapping node, but found scalar
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 17:
        nationalId: !!python/object:uuid.uuid4
                    ^
```

How do I inject a UUID value via YAML tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error message a bit intimidating at first, but after some thought, I was able to unpack it.

The parser is expecting a "mapping" node, not a scalar.  So, what happens if I add a mapping?

```
>>> yaml.load('''---
... applicant:
...   idNumbers:
...     nationalId: !!python/object:uuid.uuid4 {}''')
{'applicant': {'idNumbers': {'nationalId': UUID('71e09d1d-e84e-4ea6-855d-be1a2e91b60a')}}}
```

Additional info: http://yaml.org/type/map.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```py
import uuid
import yaml

def uuid_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', str(data))

yaml.add_representer(uuid.UUID, uuid_representer)
```

for the implicit method put in **init**.py .